# Applet signing information

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

I created a signed applet some time ago. I would now like to see with which information it is signed. How can I get these information?

Simple question, I hope there is a question answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your applet was downloaded and its certificate was accepted, you can always see your applet or application certificate information right with your JRE control Panel; here some  direction steps as

JRE control panel -> Security -> Certificates ->

[image]

Good Luck